# How to catch Django request.GET error?

Tags: django, django-forms

This view works when the query is in the database.

```
def search(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
        q = request.GET['q']
        q_school = Lawyer.objects.filter(last__icontains=q).values_list('school', flat=True)
        q_year = Lawyer.objects.filter(last__icontains=q).values_list('year_graduated', flat=True)
        lawyers = Lawyer.objects.filter(school__icontains=q_school[0]).filter(year_graduated__icontains=q_year[0]).exclude(last__icontains=q)        
        return render_to_response('search_results.html', {'lawyers': lawyers, 'query': q})
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Please submit a search term.')
```

So, if [q=delelle](http://swimswith.com/search/?q=delelle) then it finds other lawyers in the database who graduated from the same school the same year.

if [q=collins](http://swimswith.com/search/?q=collins) and collins is in the database but there are no other lawyers who graduated from the same school the same year then it gives appropriate error message "No lawyers matched your search criteria."

But if [q=moritz](http://swimswith.com/search/?q=moritz) and there is no lawyer named `moritz` in the database then it gives a 500 internal server error.

I don't understand the `request.GET['q']` notation or how I can fix this so that I can add the proper text for the case when the query is not in the database. Can you please point me in the right direction? Thanks.

**Edit re Antony Hatchkins answer**

The below code works without giving the error. I will try to incorporate the rest soon:

```
def search(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
        q = request.GET['q']
        lawyer = Lawyer.objects.filter(last__icontains=q)
        if len(lawyer)==0:
            return render_to_response('not_in_database.html', {'query': q})
        else:
            q_school = Lawyer.objects.filter(last__icontains=q).values_list('school', flat=True)
            q_year = Lawyer.objects.filter(last__icontains=q).values_list('year_graduated', flat=True)
            lawyers = Lawyer.objects.filter(school__icontains=q_school[0]).filter(year_graduated__icontains=q_year[0]).exclude(last__icontains=q)           
        return render_to_response('search_results.html', {'lawyers': lawyers, 'query': q})
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Please submit a search term.')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def search(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q', '')
    if q:
        lawyers = Lawyer.objects.filter(last__icontains=q)
        if len(lawyers)==0:
            return HttpResponse('No such lawyer')
        if len(lawyers)>1:
            return HttpResponse('Several lawyers matched')
        lawyers1 = Lawyer.objects.filter(school=lawyers[0].school).filter(year_graduated=lawyers[0].year).exclude(pk=lawyers[0].pk)        
        return render_to_response('search_results.html', {'lawyers': lawyers1, 'query': q})
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Please submit a search term.')
```

`request.GET['q']` fetches field `q` from client browser's `GET` request object

Comment: Your original function would take random item from the database if several items have matched which doubtfully is what you expect. This code will inform about the issue

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize this. But I think, you edited your initial answer. At first I couldn't make it work, then I changed a little bit, now it is working. I created a new template not_in_database.html and this will handle it. I will post the code as an edit soon. I would appreciate comments. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. Yes I fixed a typo or two.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick (not tested):

```
def search(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
        q = request.GET['q']
        try:
            q_school = Lawyer.objects.filter(last__icontains=q).values_list('school', flat=True)
            q_year = Lawyer.objects.filter(last__icontains=q).values_list('year_graduated', flat=True)
            lawyers = Lawyer.objects.filter(school__icontains=q_school[0]).filter(year_graduated__icontains=q_year[0]).exclude(last__icontains=q)        
        except Lawyer.DoesNotExist:
            lawyers = []
        return render_to_response('search_results.html', {'lawyers': lawyers, 'query': q})
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Please submit a search term.')
```

Comment: In my first try I got the 500 error again. I may be doing something wrong.